# Can not uninstall SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server

I had SQL Server 2014 before installing SQL Server 2017; after I had installed SQL Server 2017, I decided to uninstall SQL Server 2014.

I can uninstall SQL Server 2014 completely, but when I tried to uninstall SQL Server 2017, I can't. It gets stuck in this phase here in the screenshot:

[image]

How can I uninstall SQL Server 2017?

EDIT: The problem has solved. I don't know how it happened but suddenly sql 2017 had been removed from my computer...

Comment: Check your windows event log to see if there is anything there that might point to the cause of the problem. This question is probably a better fit for [su] though.

Comment: How long did you wait before determining that it's not working?

Comment: I've had that before, a reboot fixed it.